# Symfony 4 RESTful API routes working on PHP built-in server, but not on XAMPP

Tags: rest, api, symfony4

Good day.

I've been struggling for a while with [this tutorial](http://www.codeforcodes.com/rest-api-using-symfony-4/) for building a Symfony 4-based RESTful API. Everything goes well, the only thing that bothers me is that I am not able to test the API on my XAMPP web server, but only using the PHP native development server.

All routes return a 404 error message on XAMPP, but they work well with built-in server.

Why is this happening? Has it something to do with .htaccess file? I'm a newbie with this framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this issue and I have found the answer on the Symfony website: https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup/web_server_configuration.html .

You have to run the command: 
    `composer require symfony/apache-pack` 
which will install everything you need for the routing on your project, yet you have to set up the route in the `routes.yaml` file or directly in the code using the code described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html .